# How can I define repeating elements in CFG?

Tags: grammar

I am making a program that loads a cfg from a file and uses it to load programming languages into a syntax tree.

What is the proper way to define an identifier in a context free grammar. For now, I have a format like this:

```
IdentifierStart => $l$ | _; 
IdentifierChar => "$l$$IdentifierChar$" | "_$IdentifierChar$" | "$i$$IdentifierChar$" | $e$;
Identifier => "$IdentifierStart$$IdentifierChar$" $w$;
```

Format:

```
$l$ = any letter 
$e$ = epsilon
$i$ = any integer
$o$ = any operator
$n$ = new line
$w$ = whitespace
$a$ = any atom
Quotes mean the whitespace needs to match the inside of the quotes
```

While this does work, it is inefficient because it creates a deep tree when each letter could justifiably just be listed next to each other. For example, 
`Pragma => $n$ "#direct" $w$ $String$;`
with the rules:

```
IdentifierStart => $l$ | _;
IdentifierChar => "$l$$IdentifierChar$" | "_$IdentifierChar$" | "$i$$IdentifierChar$" | $e$;
Identifier => "$IdentifierStart$$IdentifierChar$";

Symbol => $l$ | $i$ | $o$ | \$$Identifier$\$;
Def => $Symbol$ $Def$ | $Symbol$ | "Def";
Assignment => $Def$ \| $Assignment$ | $Def$;
Definition => $Identifier$ "=>" $Assignment$\;;
```

creates the following tree (where each space represents a level in the tree):

```
Definition:Pragma => $n$ "#pragma" $w$ $String$;
  Identifier:Pragma
   IdentifierStart:P
    Terminal:P
   IdentifierChar:ragma
    Terminal:r
    IdentifierChar:agma
     Terminal:a
     IdentifierChar:gma
      Terminal:g
      IdentifierChar:ma
       Terminal:m
       IdentifierChar:a
        Terminal:a
  Terminal:=
  Terminal:>
  Assignment:$n$ "#direct" $w$ $String$
...
```

While this is fine in the case of an identifier, I noticed there was a problem when I realized I had to define the file format in the same recursive manner:

```
File => $ValidDirective$ $File$;
ValidDirective => $Comment$ | $Include$ | $Define$ | $Undef$ | $IfPart$ | $Error$ | $Pragma$ | $String$;
```

Each element of the file will be stored in a sub-tree of the previous element! I don't think this is acceptable because in a program with millions of lines, it will be incredibly inefficient.

Is there any way I can fix this problem while staying true to the conventions of a CFG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A true CFG does indeed define repetition via recursion, which leads to the nested parse tree you observed.

A programming language would typically use regular expressions (or something similar) to define the syntax of symbols like identifiers. In that case, parsing an identifier would result in a single token, rather than a tree, which might answer your concerns about inefficiency.

However, that approach doesn't apply to higher-level repetitive constructs, e.g. a StatementList or ArgumentList: for those, regular expressions are insufficient, and you need something at least as 'powerful' as a CFG. It's unclear if you think that storing a StatementList or ArgumentList as a deeply-nested tree is inefficient.

If you're obliged to use a true CFG, and you don't have control of the data structures created during the parsing process, you could run a post-process that converts recursive structures into non-recursive structures, but you may find that the efficiency gains are not that much.

Most programming language grammars don't confine themselves to pure CFGs, though.